# Python selenium find button using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to check whether the 'Add to cart' button exists or not on the webpage [Ebuyer][1]

Using Chromedriver.

I have tried a few things including:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/form/input[2]")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("button--add-to-basket")
```

The problem is that it just cant seem to find the button, any help will be greatly appreciated!
[1]: https://www.ebuyer.com/809813-corsair-ll-series-ll120-rgb-120mm-3-fan-pack-co-9050072-ww?_sgm_campaign=scn_8714e1eb7e000&_sgm_source=809813&_sgm_action=click

Comment: Have you taken into account the cookies pop-up? This may get in the way of viewing elements. So you will have to click the accept button separately.

Comment: @Dan added solution, try to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `Add to Basket` button, use CSS Selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".js-add-to-basket-main.js-show-loader")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using css selector works.

`css = 'input.button.button--add-to-basket' driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css)`